# Mercurial Conditional %include?

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I would like parent directories of projects to include an hgrc file that a repo in that folder inherits from, e.g.

```
~/work/
~/work/hgrc
~/work/project1/
~/work/project2/
~/personal/hgrc
~/personal/project1
~/personal/project2
~/personal/project3
```

Any project in work should inherit from `work/hgrc`, and any in personal should inherit from `personal/hgrc`. I was thinking of adding a script to `~/.hgrc` that on clone would search for any hgrc files in parent directories and `%include` them if they exist, but this has the uglyness that if I add an hgrc below it after I clone it it won't be included. Only a 5% of the time consideration, but still...

Answer (score 3):

How about putting:

```
%include ../hgrc
```

inside each repo's .hg/hgrc?  You could even do that automatically but putting this in your systemwide `/etc/mercurial/hgrc`:

```
[hooks]
post-clone = echo '%include ../hgrc' >> .hg/hgrc
```

I've not tested that hook. :)

Comment: If it doesn't work I'll tweak it, but it seems basically right, but how do I prevent it from adding the include if ../hgrc doesn't exist (or is it safe to `%include` a file that doesn't exist?) It's still a better way than having an external script. I'm going to hold out a while for a way to do this without physically changing the hgrc file (so it can handle creating a lower hgrc if one doesn't already exist), but if I don't hear something in a week or so I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Almost got this working with `post-clone = if [ -e "hgrc" ]; then echo '%include ../hgrc' >> .hg/hgrc`, but I need to be able to direct into the name of the cloned directory. I.E., if I run `hg clone proj1 proj2`, I need to prepend `.hg/hgrc` with `proj2/`.

Comment: @Jonathan: Have a try with the environment variable [`HG_PATS`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#hooks), it provides the clone source and - if explicitly given to the `clone` command - its destination. This information should be sufficient to get the destination prefix you need.

Comment: The common idiom for creating a file if it does not exist: `touch ../hgrc; echo '%include ../hgrc' >> .hg/hgrc`. But it will top out if you ever lack write access to the parent directory.

Comment: If you use the ``update`` hook instead, then you will already be in the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Ry4an's suggestion, here is an example that works for me.  I add this to my `~/.hgrc` file so it works everywhere.

```
[hooks]
# This hook adds "%include ../.hgrc" to .hg/hgrc if the .hgrc file exists in
# the top level.  This allows one to store a set of paths for example.
# See 
update = if [ -e .hgrc ] && touch .hg/hgrc                                  \
                         && ! grep -q '%include \.\./\.hgrc' .hg/hgrc; then \
           echo '%include ../.hgrc' >> .hg/hgrc;                            \
         fi
```

This hook adds the line `%include ../.hgrc` to the `.hg/hgrc` file iff the file `.hgrc` exists in the top level of the repo.  Note that by using the `update` hook, we bypass the issue of the with `post-clone` clone hook of having to try to figure out the directory name of the target clone from environmental variables.